# How do i use a parameter with a api call using retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I need to use a parameter to access a different api query depending on what the user choses.

I am trying to get to http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/api/characters/house/Slytherin

```
    @GET("api/characters/house")
suspend fun getAllHouse(@Query("/") search: String ): House
```

Answer (score 0):

You want add variable inside your path like this

```
@GET("api/characters/house/{city}")
```

and you will pass it on parameter function like this

```
suspend fun getAllHouse(@Path("city") city: String ): House
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code and concatenate response url string parameters will get this [data](http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/api/characters/house/Slytherin)

```
      @GET
      suspend fun getAllHouse(@Url String url): Call<List<House>>
```